# Is there a way to wipe Windows off a Surface Pro and install Linux?

Tags: linux

I’ve tried to install Linux on a surface pro however the best I’ve done is through a USB stick, I want to wipe Windows completely and make it Linux only is there any way this could be achieved?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/7kb1ky/guide_installing_linux_on_surfaceseries_devices/

Answer (score 0):

It depends which model you are using. There are many! Suggest looking at [r/SurfaceLinux](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/7kazwp/current_state_of_surfaceseries_devices/) and also determining if you plan to go back to Windows or [dual-boot](http://blog.davidelner.com/dual-booting-ubuntu-14-10-on-the-surface-pro-3/) and thus may need to generate your own machine-owner-key to work with UEFI.

Answer (score -1):

I installed Kubuntu 19 on surface pro using USB. Worked fine. Just remember to use "Erase Disk and Install" option to use the whole disk when you are installing OS. I had to remove the old encrypted Windows partitions first (that's the "erase" part).